# "No rule to make target" error when adding an external library in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, wxwidgets

I am new in the world of Qt. I would like to add an external library of wxMSW-2.8.12 in Qt Creator. In order to do that, I right-clicked on my .pro file and clicked on "Add Library", then I select "External Library". I finally choose the Library file, click on "Static" for "Linkage".

This is what I got automatically from Qt Creator:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../wxMSW-2.8.12/lib/vc_lib/ -lwxbase28ud_xml    
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../wxMSW-2.8.12/lib/vc_lib/ -lwxbase28ud_xmld 
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../wxMSW-2.8.12/lib/vc_lib/ -lwxbase28ud_xml

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../wxMSW-2.8.12/lib/vc_lib DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../wxMSW-2.8.12/lib/vc_lib

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../wxMSW-2.8.12/lib/vc_lib/libwxbase28ud_xml.a 
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../wxMSW-2.8.12/lib/vc_lib/libwxbase28ud_xmld.a 
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../wxMSW-2.8.12/lib/vc_lib/wxbase28ud_xml.lib    
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../wxMSW-2.8.12/lib/vc_lib/wxbase28ud_xmld.lib
else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../wxMSW-2.8.12/lib/vc_lib/libwxbase28ud_xml.a
```

But, when running, I get this error:

```
:-1: erreur&nbsp;: No rule to make target 'C:/Qt/Qt5.2.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/testConverter/../../../../../../wxMSW-2.8.12/lib/vc_lib/libwxbase28ud_xmld.a', needed by 'debug\testConverter.exe'.  Stop.
```

I tried to clean and rerun qmake but with any success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What compiler are you using? The lib you're trying to add was compiled with Visual Studio.

Comment: I am compiling with MinGW and the lib was compiled with VS yes. I would like to use VS, how should I change the compiler in Qt?

Comment: You will need to have `Qt` compiled with VS. Is it?

Comment: In my Tools > Options... > Compile and Run, I there are detected MinGW and Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 9.0. I I have a screenshot of it but I can't put it here...

Comment: Screenshot of my Compile & Run: can you see it?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/KXcuP.png

Comment: Mm, I had the same problem as you with the `Compiler and Run`. In my case, I had `Qt` built with MinGW. So even Visual Studio was detected, I couldn't use it. I had to built `Qt` again from source with Visual Studio in order to be able to use it with Qt Creator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48481/discussion-between-colet-and-adri-c-s)

Comment: Ok, I havenow installed this qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2010_opengl-5.2.1. I have another question: I have an application that was compiled with VS 2008, do you think that it could run with VS 2010 compiler as well?